# C# Form, After resizing Form, Image could not draw out of original form size

Tags: c#, forms, resize, crop

Summary:
It just doesn't draw outside of the initial form size. I can scale down, just not scale up, it get cropped off.

Description if Summary isn't clear enough:
Therefore if my form is initially size 1000,800. My image drawn will never be larger than 1000,800 after scaling.

It will be cropped off, if I scaled the form to size 2000,1600. The image will be cropped halfway away both below and to the right, therefore only drawing the top left part.

I am sure my scaling works correct since it works as long as I set my form to be 2000,1600 on creation.

.
.
Code as requested, though I'm not sure if it matters.
.

```
mapDrawer.DrawImage( map1,
    new RectangleF(0, 0, ImageSizeX * scale, ImageSizeY * scale),
    new RectangleF(0, 0, ImageSizeX, ImageSizeY),
    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Where scale is form.size/map_size.
And I took the smaller scale of x or y.

Comment: Show your code please...

Comment: Should "Summary" read "Riddle" above?

Comment: Okay? And do you scale your mapDrawer, whatever that is?

Comment: @J. Steen: My best guess would be a `Graphics`.

Comment: @Tharwen Yeah, but that `Graphics` object belongs to something. Maybe the form, maybe a control on the form that doesn't scale with the form.

Comment: No idea why this question was downvoted, it's a real problem and the solution has been given, once again thanks to Hans Passant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *mapDrawer* object is the problem although it is impossible to see from the inadequate snippet.  It is no doubt a Graphics object that you created early, maybe in the form's Load event.  It has a clipping region that was based on the size of the form at that time.  If you then make the form larger by resizing it, you'll find out that this copied Graphics object cannot draw beyond its original bounds.  It can't.

Never copy Graphics objects, always do the painting in a Paint event handler and use the passed e.Graphics object.  This also ensures that double-buffering works correctly, something you are likely to want to turn on.  Use the Invalidate() method if something happens that should redraw the image.

Comment: Was it you who made the comment on my answer above? If so, I've made some corrections. If it wasn't you, then I've still made some corrections, but I've also given you an unnecessary comment notification.

Comment: Yeah, that was me.  I decided it would be better to post an answer to explain why it was going wrong.

Comment: I'll have a look at this, and see if this is the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you need to redraw the image when the Form is repainted:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    g.DrawImage(map1,
        new RectangleF(0, 0, ImageSizeX * scale, ImageSizeY * scale),
        new RectangleF(0, 0, ImageSizeX, ImageSizeY),
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

To call this method when the form is resized (or anything else that forces it to redraw), you should add a handle on the Paint event in the form's constructor:

```
Paint += new EventHandler(Form1_Paint);
```